# React: what is the correct syntax for boolean check

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have a boolean prop in react and i am trying to use it as shown below:

```
const MyComponent = ({ prop1, prop2, isBoolean }) => {
...do something..
return (
 if (isBoolean) ? (do this) : (do that)
}
```

So i am saying if isBoolean is true then do this else do that. is this the correct syntax?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do conditional rendering inside the `return ( expression )` you will need to use a ternary operator.

```
const MyComponent = ({ prop1, prop2, isBoolean }) => {
    // ...do something..
    return (
       { isBoolean ? (do this) : (do that) }
    );
};
```

You could also perform your condition before the return statement as follows:

```
const MyComponent = ({ prop1, prop2, isBoolean }) => {
    // ...do something..

    const DOMToRender = isBoolean ? this : that;

    return (
       { isBoolean ? (do this) : (do that) }
    );
};
```

You could also repleace `const DOMToRender = isBoolean ? this : that;` with and if/else statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use ternary operator, you have to remove `if` keyword.

```
isBoolean ? (do this) : (do that)
```

Then it will be indeed a proper syntax.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not correct syntax in JS. You've mixed `if` statement and [tenary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) in one statement. Correct syntax is either:

- If statement

  ```
  if (isBoolean) {
    //do this
  } else {
    //do that
  }
  ```
- or tenary operator

  ```
  isBoolean ? expression1 : expression2;
  ```

Answer (score 0):

No, either simply:

```
isBoolean ? this : that
```

Or, for more complex (multi-line) code:

```
if (isBoolean) {
  this
} else {
  that
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And if it is possible to be undefined at any point (ie by default) you can force it into a boolean value for the ternary by the double bang!!

```
return !!isBoolean ? (do this) : (do that)
```